# Find previous Post efficiently (keystoneJS)

Tags: javascript, performance, mongodb, express, keystonejs

I'm looking to find the previous post. I know I can just load all the posts and check from there.. but that seems data heavy. Is there a cleaner way to query for just the previous post? Perhaps with sort? or perhaps there is a way to limit the amount of data retrieved.. like only the slugs so that it is less data heavy?

I just want to make this a light request and find the next post.

This is my current solution

```
var keystone = require('keystone');

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
    var view = new keystone.View(req, res),
        locals = res.locals;

    // Set locals
    locals.section = 'news';
    locals.filters = {
        post: req.params.post
    }
    locals.data = {
        previousPost: []
    }

    // Load the current post
    view.on('init', function(next) {

        var q = keystone.list('Post').model.findOne({
            state: 'published',
            slug: locals.filters.post
        }).populate('author categories');

        q.exec(function(err, result) {
            locals.data.post = result;
            next(err);
        });

    });

    // Load previous post
    view.on('init', function(next) {
        var q = keystone.list('Post').model.find().where('state', 'published').sort('-publishedDate');
        q.exec(function(err, results) {
            allPosts = results;
            for (var i = 0; i < allPosts.length; i++) {
                if (allPosts[i]["slug"] === locals.filters.post) {
                    locals.data.previousPost = allPosts[i+1];
                    next(err);
                }
            }
        });
    });

    // Render the view
    view.render('post');    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding mongo query is:

`db.posts.find({state: "published", publishedDate: {$lt: currentpost.publishedDate}}).sort({publishedDate: -1}).limit(1)`

The corresponding keystone/mongoose query I believe is:

`var q = keystone.list('Post').model.find({state: "published", publishedDate: {$lt: currentpost.publishedDate}}).sort('-publishedDate').limit(1);`

If you want to select just, for example, the title of the post then you can add a select query filter:

`var q = keystone.list('Post').model.find({state: "published", publishedDate: {$lt: currentpost.publishedDate}}).sort('-publishedDate').select('title').limit(1);`

The equivalent mongo query would be something like:

`db.posts.find({state: "published", publishedDate: {$lt: currentpost.publishedDate}},{title: 1}).sort({publishedDate: -1}).limit(1)`

And there's different other ways to write these queries :-)

Comment: Thanks, much quicker — 1/3 the time
var q = keystone.list('Post').model.find({state: "published", publishedDate: {$lt: currentpost.publishedDate}}).sort('-publishedDate').limit(1);

Answer (score 1):

You could try checking for posts that were published before the current post: `.where('publishedDate', { $lt: currentPost.publishedDate } )`, continue to sort by publishedDate and then have a `.limit(1)`. That should make the request a bit 'lighter'

Comment: Thanks... you both answered my question — @webteckie was just more comprehensive